# Omnet++ multiple submodues

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am trying to simulate 100 submodules. Is there a simple way to define 100 submodules in few lines?

```
  submodules:
    sampler1: Sam1 ;
    sampler2: Sam1 ;
    sampler3: Sam1;
    sampler4: Sam1;
    sampler5: Sam1 ;
    sampler6: Sam1 ;
```

Without doing as above is there any other simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, write:

```
 submodules:
    sampler[100]: Sam1;
```

Comment: D, Thank you for the answer. How ever I cant simulate beyond 4 submodules. it gives this error. "(omnetpp::cMessage)sampleEvent: par(int): Has no parameter #4 -- in module (Sam1) Net.sampler1[4] (id=6), during network initialization"

It works perfect up to 4 submodules.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add NED code of your modules as well as `omnetpp.ini`?

Comment: Please do not edit this question. Submit separate questions for unrelated problems.

Comment: @JerzyD., I created a new question with .ned & .ini files. Please take a look. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261964/omnet-error-when-simulating-multiple-submodules)