# Omnet++ error when simulating multiple submodules

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am trying to simulate 10 submodules. But omnet++ gives an error when the number of submodules are greater than five. here is the error:

> (omnetpp::cMessage)sampleEvent: par(int): Has no parameter #4 -- in module (Sam1) Net.sampler1[4] (id=6), during network initialization

My .ned file

```
simple Sam1
{
parameters:
    @display("i=block/routing");
gates:
    inout gate[];  // declare two way connections
}

simple Svr1
{
parameters:
    @display("i=block/process");
gates:
    inout gate[];  // declare two way connections
}


network Net
{
@display("bgb=670.56,274.32");
types:
    channel Ch extends ned.DelayChannel
    {
        delay = 100ns;
    }

submodules:
    sampler1[10]: Sam1 {
        @display("p=334,127;is=l");
    }
    server: Svr1 {
        parameters:
            @display("i=,gold;p=109.21999,88.899994");
    }


connections:
    for i=0..9 {
        server.gate++ <--> Ch <--> sampler1[i].gate++;
    }
}
```

omnetpp.ini file

```
[General]
[Config Net]
network = Net
record-eventlog = true
```

sam1 class

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class Sam1 : public cSimpleModule
{
  private:
    simtime_t timeout;  // timeout
    cMessage *sampleEvent;  // holds pointer to the  self-message
    int seq;  // message sequ ence number
    cMessage *message;  // message that has to be re-sent on timeout
    double vK;
    double vM;
    double threshold = 1.0;
    int counter;
    double xmean = 0.01;
    double xsigma = 1;
    double sensigma = 0.1;
    double x;
    double zOut = 0.0;
    double previousSentTime = 0.0;
    int samplerID;
    double xSum;

    long numSent;
    long numReceived;
    long totalEvents;
    cLongHistogram SampleStats;
    cOutVector SampleVector;
    cLongHistogram interSampleStats;
    cOutVector interSampleVector;
    cLongHistogram sentSampleStats;
    cOutVector sentSampleVector;
    cOutVector constructedSignal;


  public:
    Sam1();
    virtual ~Sam1();

  protected:
    virtual cMessage *generateNewMessage();
    virtual void sampleAndSend(cMessage *msg);
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;

    // The finish() function is called by OMNeT++ at the end of the simulation:
    virtual void finish();
};

Define_Module(Sam1);

Sam1::Sam1()
{
    sampleEvent = message = nullptr;
}

Sam1::~Sam1()
{
    cancelAndDelete(sampleEvent);
    delete message;
}

void Sam1::initialize()
{

    // Initialize variables.
    vM = 0;
    seq = 0;
    timeout = 100.0;        // in every 100 second
    sampleEvent = new cMessage("sampleEvent");
    xSum = 0.0;
    counter = 1;
    numSent = 0;
    numReceived = 0;
    totalEvents = 0;
    WATCH(numSent);
    WATCH(totalEvents);
    samplerID = getIndex();

    interSampleStats.setName("interSampleStats");
    interSampleStats.setRangeAutoUpper(0, 10, 1.5);
    interSampleVector.setName("interSample");

    SampleStats.setName("SampleStats");
//    interSampleStats.setRangeAutoUpper(0, 10, 1.5);
    SampleVector.setName("Sample");

    sentSampleStats.setName("sentSampleStats");
//    interSampleStats.setRangeAutoUpper(0, 10, 1.5);
    sentSampleVector.setName("sentSample");
    constructedSignal.setName("constructedSignal");

    // Generate and send initial message.
    EV << "Sending initial message\n";
    message = generateNewMessage();
    sampleAndSend(message);
//    scheduleAt(simTime()+timeout, sampleEvent);
}

void Sam1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg == sampleEvent) {
//        EV << "sampling Again\n";
        // Ready to send another one.
        message = generateNewMessage();
        sampleAndSend(message);
    }

}


cMessage *Sam1::generateNewMessage()
{
    // Generate a message

    cMessage *msg = new cMessage("sampleEvent");

    double t1 = simTime().dbl() * 1000;

    msg->addPar("sampleValue");
    x = normal(xmean, xsigma) + normal(xmean, sensigma);
    xSum = x + xSum;
    msg->par("sampleValue").setDoubleValue(xSum);
    msg->addPar("counter");
    msg->par("counter").setLongValue(counter);
    msg->addPar("generatedTimestamp");
    msg->par("generatedTimestamp").setDoubleValue(t1);
    msg->addPar("samplerName");
    msg->par(samplerID);


    counter = counter +1;
    totalEvents++;
    return msg;
}

void Sam1::sampleAndSend(cMessage *msg)
{
    double sampleValue = msg->par("sampleValue").doubleValue();
    double genTimestamp = msg->par("generatedTimestamp").doubleValue();

    cMessage *copy = (cMessage *)msg->dup();
    vK = sampleValue-vM;
//    EV << vK << " vK \n";
    if(fabs(sampleValue-vM) > threshold){
        vM = sampleValue;
        zOut = sampleValue;

        // In this example, we just pick a random gate to send it on.
            // We draw a random number between 0 and the size of gate `out[]'.
        int n = gateSize("gate");
        int k = intuniform(0, n-1);



        send(copy, "gate$o", k);

        double t2 = simTime().dbl() * 1000;    // sample time in milli seconds
        double interSample = t2 - previousSentTime;
        previousSentTime = genTimestamp;

        numSent++;

        interSampleVector.record(interSample);
        interSampleStats.collect(interSample);

        sentSampleVector.record(1);
        sentSampleStats.collect(1);

    }else{
        zOut = vM;
        sentSampleVector.record(0);
        sentSampleStats.collect(0);
    }

    EV << "vM " << vM << endl;
//    EV << "sampling Again. node " << simTime() << endl;

    SampleVector.record(sampleValue);
    SampleStats.collect(sampleValue);

    constructedSignal.record(zOut);

    scheduleAt(simTime()+timeout, sampleEvent);
}

void Sam1::finish(){
    // This function is called by OMNeT++ at the end of the simulation.
    EV << "Sent:     " << numSent << endl;
    EV << "Total Events:     " << totalEvents << endl;
    float rate = (float)numSent/totalEvents;
    EV << "Traffic Reduction: " << rate << endl;

    EV << "Threshold:    " << threshold << endl;
    EV << "Signal Mean:    " << xmean << endl;
    EV << "Signam sigma:    " << xsigma << endl;
    EV << "Sensor Sigma:    " << sensigma << endl;


    EV << "Inter Sample Time, min:    " << interSampleStats.getMin() << endl;
    EV << "Inter Sample Time, max:    " << interSampleStats.getMax() << endl;
    EV << "Inter Sample Time, mean:   " << interSampleStats.getMean() << endl;
    EV << "Inter Sample Time, stddev: " << interSampleStats.getStddev() << endl;

    recordScalar("#sent", numSent);
    recordScalar("#total", totalEvents);
    interSampleStats.recordAs("inter sample");
    SampleStats.recordAs("sample");
    sentSampleStats.recordAs("sent sample");
}


/**
 * Sends back an acknowledgement -- or not.
 */
class Svr1 : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(Svr1);

void Svr1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

        double sampleValue = msg->par("sampleValue").doubleValue();
        long counter = msg->par("counter").longValue();
        long samplerID = msg->par("samplerName").longValue();
        EV << sampleValue << " received, sending back an acknowledgment from sampler "<< samplerID << ". counter " << counter <<  "\n";

        delete msg;

        // In this example, we just pick a random gate to send it on.
            // We draw a random number between 0 and the size of gate `out[]'.
        int n = gateSize("gate");
        int k =  msg->getArrivalGate()->getIndex();


        EV << "n: " << n << "k: " << k << endl;

//        send(new cMessage("ack"), "gate$o", k);

}
```

Comment: The NED file looks OK. Could you add to your question code of `Sam1` class?

Comment: Hi @JerzyD., I added the class. please take a look